# Problema al utilizar mPDF

Tags: php, html, laravel

Hola gente de Stackoverflow, el problema que estoy teniendo es que quiero transformar una tabla de reportes en un archivo pdf, el proyecto lo estoy haciendo con laravel. Al ejecutar php artisan serve y ir a la ruta de la vista /obrasSociales/imprimirfactura me tira todo un texto desconocido(el de la imagen), pero al ejecutarlo sin php artisan serve sino desde localhost me imprime el texto perfectamente. Ya probé con FPDF y ahora con mPDF y las 2 librerías me tiran un texto desconocido. Seguiré probando pero mientras tanto esperaba una solución, de ultima si lo soluciono publico la solución por si otro tiene el mismo problema.

Laravel 5.7
FPDF v1.81 o mPDF v7.x
Windows 10 Home
Codigo de imprimirfactura.blade.php:

```
<?php
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

[image: Error al ejecutar con php artisan serve]

[image: Funciona perfecto a travez de localhost]

Comment: ¿ Le estás poniendo el `header('Content-Type: application/pdf');` ? Por lo que entiendo, creo que el navegador lo está intentando interpretar como `.html`, que es el *Content-type* por defecto de `PHP`.

Comment: Por ahora lo solucioné descargando la librería barryvdh/laravel-dompdf a través de composer, y configurando en config/app.php para poder usarla. De ultima si me da problemas esta librería, pruebo de nuevo mPDF o FPDF aplicando tu solución. Creo que ese era el problema de todas formas, mil gracias man